# Affiliate QR Code system for App Downloads but also In-App purchases

Tags: ios, flutter, qr-code, deep-linking, affiliate

Currently developing a vehicle rental App in flutter for iOS/Android.

Our business has an affiliate system whereby affiliates are assigned a unique QR Code for app download. When a new user scans QR Code, the system needs to not only direct/attribute that App Store download to the affiliate, but also any rentals the user makes should attribute a % of rental fees to the affiliate.

How exactly can this be done?